# How to save imported file into separated folder within the project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Imported an excel file , That I want to save in a folder named excelfiles within the project. Now imported file stores straightly within the project. how to map to save files to my excelfile folder within the folder? My code is

```
protected void importnpatscoew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (fileuploadExcel.HasFile)
   {
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
        string Extension = Path.GetExtension(fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
        string FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["excelimports"];
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath(FolderPath + FileName);
        fileuploadExcel.SaveAs(FilePath);
        Import_To_Grid(FilePath, Extension, "YES");
   }
   else
   {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please select a file first..!!');", true);
   }
}
```

Comment: let me understand, at the moment your excel file is saved in **"/myProject/"** folder, and you want it to be saved int **"/myProject/excelfiles /"** ?

Comment: @ Banana, yes exactly..how it ispossible??

Comment: have a look [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116(v=vs.140).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your project root is named MyProject and you want to save to a folder name excelfiles under MyProject you could use

```
FileUpload.SaveAs("~/ExcelFiles/yourfile.extension")
```

Please note that

```
~/ resolves to the application root.
/ resolves to the site root.
```

So in your case(application root and site root are both MyProject) you can also use `FileUpload.SaveAs("/ExcelFiles/yourfile.extension")`